# ADB screen record command to mirror Android screen to PC via USB

Tags: adb, screencast

I am trying to mirror android device screen though ADB commands from the command prompt for quite a long time. Recently I saw a post in stackoverflow with the following command which mirrors the screen when executed in the command prompt.

**adb exec-out screenrecord --output-format=h264 --size 540x960 - | ffplay -framerate 60 -framedrop -bufsize 16M -**

From what I have read is that this commands stores the Frame buffer somewhere in a file, and my question is where is this file stored and how can I access this file(Frame buffer) in a desktop application for example written in C#.

Any help or hint will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy)? From my perspective this project is what you want to build.

Answer (score 0):

To know where the file is stored (if any) then you can use Process Monitor (on Windows) to see where this file is created.